How to Mock Retryable for a Junit test in springboot
Retryable is not working when I use Mockito in Springboot for a Junit test case
Below is my code
Dao Class:
@Component
public class RetryDao {
    public Integer getNumber(String s) throws CustomException{
        try {
             return Integer.parseInt(s);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            log.error("Error in DAO");
            throw new CustomException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

Service Class:
@Service
public class RetryService {
   @Autowired
   RetryDao dao;
   
   @Retryable(value = (CustomException.class), maxAttempts = 3, backoff = @BackOff(200))
   public String retry(String number) throws CustomException {
      log.info("Exception Retry");
      return dao.getNumber(number);
   }
}

If I write a Junit Test Class without using Mockito concept, then Retryable is working:
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(WebEnvironment = SpringBootTester.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = MainApplication.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {RetryDao.class, RetryService.class})
public class RetryServiceTest {
    @Autowired
    RetryDao dao;

    @Autowired
    RetryService service;

    @Test
    public void getNumbetTest() {
       try {
            String response = service.retry("a");
            log.info("Response: {}", response);
       } catch (Exception e) {
         log.error("Error in Test");
       }
       

    }
}

In this case, Retryable is working and getting below logs
Exception Retry
Error in DAO
Exception Retry
Error in DAO
Exception Retry
Error in DAO
Error in Test

But When I use same with Mockito concept, then control is coming out for the first exception without doing a retry
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(WebEnvironment = SpringBootTester.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = MainApplication.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {RetryDao.class, RetryService.class})
public class RetryServiceTest {
    @Mock  // here tried with @MockBean also
    RetryDao dao;

    @InjectMocks
    RetryService service;

    @Test
    public void getNumbetTest() {
       try {
            // Tried mocking the dao here also 
            // RetryDao dao = mock(RetryDao.class)
            CustomException ce = new CustomeException("alphabet Error")
            When(dao.getNumber(anyString()).thenThrow(cr).thenThrow(cr).thenThrow(cr)
            String response = service.retry("a");
            log.info("Response: {}", response);
       } catch (Exception e) {
         log.error("Error in Test");
       }
       

    }
}

In this case, Retryable not working and getting below logs
Exception Retry
Error in Test


@Retry is a Spring annotation/concept. @InjectMocks is Mockito. Your test is not using Spring, but creates the fields via Mockito – Spring is not involved. Since you are not using beans, but new instances, Spring doesn't even know about them. If you want to test Spring functionality, you have to use Spring. Are you maybe looking for @MockBean?

I already tried with @MockBean also, I mentioned same in the question

@MockBean is a Spring annotation, @InjectMocks is a Mockito annotation. You cannot use them together. Either @SpringBootTest + @MockBean + @Autowired or @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class) + @Mock + @InjectMocks. Without the Mockito extension, the annotations aren't even picked up. @RunWith is a JUnit 4 annotation (Superseded by @ExtendWith in JUnit 5), but it shouldn't be necessary since your test is already annotated with @SpringBootTest.

ohh okay.. thanks for the quick response and solution. When I used @SpringBootTest + @Autowired + @MockBean combination, it worked

When I used combination of @SpringBootTest + @Autowired + @MockBean then it worked. Below is complete code
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(WebEnvironment = SpringBootTester.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = MainApplication.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {RetryDao.class, RetryService.class})
public class RetryServiceTest {
    @MockBean also
    RetryDao dao;

    @Autowired
    RetryService service;

    @Test
    public void getNumbetTest() {
       try {
            // Tried mocking the dao here also 
            // RetryDao dao = mock(RetryDao.class)
            CustomException ce = new CustomeException("alphabet Error")
            When(dao.getNumber(anyString()).thenThrow(cr).thenThrow(cr).thenThrow(cr)
            String response = service.retry("a");
            log.info("Response: {}", response);
       } catch (Exception e) {
         log.error("Error in Test");
       }
   }
}

then I got below Logs:
Exception Retry
Exception Retry
Exception Retry
Error in Test


Remove @RunWith(SpringRunner.class), you already have @SpringBootTest.

JUnit 5 has been out for 6.5 years now, with the new annotation @ExtendWith
